# extract day of the month and hour of a given date format shell scripting

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I am writing a script where I am looking for help. I am using date format in my script as below (YYYY MM DD HH MM):

```
$ echo $DT
202002252216
```

Now my requirement is to compare two dates listed in the file and calculate output in hours.

```
cat /home/postgres/pglinux_mm_cfg
MM_START=202002261015
MM_END=202002261530
MM_SERVER=pglinux
```

Here is my script, `timediff.sh`

```
ENV=/home/postgres
MM_START=`grep MM_START ${ENV}/\`hostname\`_mm_cfg |awk -F"=" '{print $2}'`
MM_END=`grep MM_END ${ENV}/\`hostname\`_mm_cfg |awk -F"=" '{print $2}'`

MPHR=60
STARTIME=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M -d ${MM_START})
ENDTIME=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M  -d ${MM_END})
MINUTES=$(( ($ENDTIME - $STARTIME) / $MPHR ))

echo $STARTIME $ENDTIME $MINUTES
```

How to get date difference between MM_END AND MM_START in day's and hours?

I am using `ksh`.

Comment: Double-quote your variables when you use them (`"$MM_START"` instead of just `$MM_START`, for example). Also, start your script with `#!/bin/ksh` or whatever fits the path for your shell. Finally, do not use all capitals for your variable names - they are likely to clash with existing reserved names - instead use lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Should work (but untested) on `ksh`:

```
echo "$MM_START", "$MM_END", $(( ($(date -d"${MM_END:0:8} ${MM_END:8}" +%s) - $(date -d"${MM_START:0:8} ${MM_START:8}" +%s) )/ 60 ))
202002261015, 202002261530, 315
```

This uses shell's

- "arithmetic expansion" `$((...))` to perform the difference and division
- "command substitution" `$(...)` (twice, for the two `date` commands) that " allows the output of a command to replace the command name" (c.f. `man bash`)
- "Parameter Expansion / Substring Expansion" to extract substrings from a variable.

After all, it produces two "epoch seconds" that are subtracted, and the result divided by 60 to get at minutes. Be aware that `bash` only performs integer arithmetics (can't speak for `ksh`).

Comment: Hello RudiC, Thank you so much for piece of code, It is working fine, tested couple of time.  How do i Understand the code `$(( ($(date -d"${MM_END:0:8} ${MM_END:8}" +%s) - $(date -d"${MM_START:0:8} ${MM_START:8}" +%s) )/ 60 ))` .  Kindly explain

Comment: See my edit ...

Comment: RudiC, Thank you so much. it is working fine. My apologies for very late reply

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you had in mind, but this is much simpler with a proper
programming language. For example with PHP:

```
<?php
$o1 = date_create('202002261015');
$o2 = date_create('202002261530');
$o3 = date_diff($o2, $o1);
echo 'days: ', $o3->d, ', hours: ', $o3->h, "\n";
```

Result:

```
days: 0, hours: 5
```

https://php.net/function.date-diff